# Examples using Massive

Tags: .net, massive

Could anyone point me to some examples of how to uses Rob Conerys Massive Data Access routines. I couldn't find much using google, maybe I am using the wrong search criteria? Preferably something for someone new to dynamics in the .net framework

Comment: If you don't get anything better, IIRC we have some "massive" code in the "dapper-dot-net" test suite (for performance comparisons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tekpub MVC 3 series uses Massive for the data access, code can be found here -

https://github.com/tekpub/mvc3

Comment: I don't see Massive.cs in there anywhere.

Comment: It's used in all the classes (except AccountModel.cs) within the 'Model' folder - https://github.com/tekpub/mvc3/tree/master/Source/VidPub.Web/Model

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this one can help

[Massive: 400 Lines of Data Access Happiness](http://rob.conery.io/2011/02/16/massive-400-lines-of-data-access-happiness/)